# $V(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and $V(xz−y^2,yw−z^2,xw−yz)$ are isomorphic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I saw a statement that read:

$$X:=V(x^2+y^2+z^2)\subset \mathbb{P}^2$$ and
$$Y :=V(xz−y^2,yw−z^2,xw−yz)\subset \mathbb{P}^3$$

are isomorphic.

I don't immediately see why this is true. Thoughts?

Comment: What field are you working on? Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic not 2, both are isomorphic to the projective line. The first is the line embedded by quadrics, the second, embedded using cubics.

Comment: The statement is assuming and algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, so yes, not 2. What do you mean by quadrics and cubics?

Comment: You can embed the projective line in $\mathbb{P}^n$ using homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ as follows. $(u,v)\mapsto (u^n, u^{n-1}v,\ldots, uv^{n-1}, v^n)$. If you use $n=2$, you get the curve in the plane defined by $y^2-xz=0$, which you can easily check is isomorphic to the one you describe by a change of variables. If you use $n=3$, you get the curve as you have in 3-space.